# I cant use Variable after initialize in the onResponse volley

Tags: java, android, json

For geting the direct link , i should parse the

json in Adapter . In `onBindViewHolder` where the onClicklistener` of button

called . I get The direct download link .

> This is `OnBinderViewHolder` of My Adapter where json is parsed

```
 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
       ===> String DownloadUrl;

        holder.txtTitle.setText(questionha.get(position).getQuestionTitle());
        holder.txtDesc.setText(questionha.get(position).getQuestionDesc());
        holder.txtCntDown.setText(questionha.get(position).getQuestionDownCnt());
        holder.txtAuthorName.setText(questionha.get(position).getQuestionAuthorName());
        Glide.with(holder.itemView.getContext()).load(questionha.get(position).getQuestionAuthorPic()).into(holder.imgAuthorPic);
        holder.txtDate.setText(questionha.get(position).getQuestionDate());
        holder.btnDownload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                JsonObjectRequest volleyRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(questionha.get(position).getQuestionDownLink(), new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        if (response != null || response.length() > 0) {
                            try {
                              ===>DownloadUrl = response.getString("link");
                                Toast.makeText(context, DownloadUrl, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        error.printStackTrace();
                    }
                });
                AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(volleyRequest);


                //Toast.makeText(context, DownloadUrl, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager) context.getSystemService (Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
               ===>DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(DownloadUrl));;
                request.setTitle(questionha.get(position).getQuestionTitle())
                        .setDescription("در حال دانلود")
                        .setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(context, "question", questionha.get(position).getQuestionTitle());
                long enqueueId = downloadManager.enqueue(request);

            }
        });

    }
```

Now when I want to use `DownloadUrl` variable in for url of DownloadManger I got this error in volley `onResponse` that say:

> Variable "DownloadUrl" is Accessed from inner class , needs to be
>   final

And when i set final `Donwloadurl` it say :

> cannot Assign a Value to final Variable "DownloadUrl"

Thanks.

Comment: dont you  think that downloading stuff should be written inside `onResponse` where you get response.

Comment: yes , i do it . but it's not good sulution

Comment: declare and init `DownloadUrl` inside `onResponse` only.

Comment: it's ok ,but when i want use string DownloadUrl in Method Uri.parse(DownlaodUrl) . it'snt work and when i add string of url in like Uri.parse("http://www.hello.com/download.apk") . it's work . what's your idea ?